# Context of Kipling poem Dane-Geld

Tags: poetry, historical-context, rudyard-kipling

Kipling's poem [Dane-Geld](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poem/poems_danegeld.htm) is a warning about submitting to blackmail.  It makes the point that if you pay blackmail then the blackmailer will come back and demand more. Therefore you should never pay.

It begins:

> IT IS always a temptation to an armed and agile nation
> To call upon a neighbour and to say: –
> "We invaded you last night – we are quite prepared to fight,
> Unless you pay us cash to go away."

Was this written in response to anything specific?  Was there at the time of writing any armed and agile nation demanding money or other benefits from England?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Background' notes provided state that the poem comes from Kipling and Fletcher's *A School History of England* of 1911. I found a commentary on the book [here](https://www.uncomfortableoxford.com/a-primer-for-empire-fletcher-and-kiplings-school-history-of-england#:%7E:text=26%20May%202020-,Charles%20Robert%20Leslie%20Fletcher%20(1857%2D1934)%20and%20Rudyard%20Kipling,of%20ideology%20and%20partisan%20politics.)

Comment: You can find their book [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_School_History_of_England/ZUphDEQv4f8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=dane-geld) on Google books. In connection with the poem, the book discusses Ethelred the Unready, and the poem describes Ethelred's dealings with the Danes very well. Since it was written in 1911, you could ask ir it was also written in response to events in the lead-up to WW1. Absent a comment from Kipling or Fletcher, I don't think there's any way to settle this. And it seems to describe Ethelred the Unready's reign better than any event that happened in 1911.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you comment on the later queries in the question? "Was this written in response to anything specific?" and "Was there at the time of writing any armed and agile nation demanding money or other benefits from England?"

Comment: No, I don't know enough about the history of that period. I was just referring you to the useful background notes provided by that Kipling website.